# Create and Configure Facebook Apps via API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-rest-api

I'm looking for a solution to create and configure Facebook Apps via the Facebook APIs.
It doens't matter if its Graph API / FQL or REST API but I couldn't find any way to do this.

Comment: The [Spring Social Facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/) project is an extension to [Spring Social](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/) that enables integration with Facebook.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with my question.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4719260/how-to-programatically-create-a-facebook-application-via-js-sdk-or-open-graph-ap

Comment: Also, official bug to follow on Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295627350461318

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't find because this is not possible.

Facebook decided not to support app management and creation using the API, in order to avoid applications created or edited by bots.

Only a few actions are possible using the API:

- Migration (like migrating to OAuth2, ...)
- Restriction (Geographical, age...)
- User ban (add/remove)
- Test User Creation/edition/deletion

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/ for more info.

You'll notice one of the first sentence: "**To create, administer or delete applications developers must go to the Developer Application.**"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Legacy REST API to set (and get) application properties:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.setAppProperties/

But no create API exists, and probably never will due to dirty spammers...