# Create and setup facebook bot through api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I looked into motion.ai and how they make facebook bots. I noticed that they somehow manage to connect everything automatically (app link with pages, secrets, hashes, webhooks setup and all that stuff).

According to this [Create and Configure Facebook Apps via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726219/create-and-configure-facebook-apps-via-api) that can't be done through the API.

Anyone have any clues how they set this all up? I'm working on a system that should do something similar (the setup stuff for instancing apps and setting them up, not the whole bot managing system). I thought it will have to be done all manually, but somehow they managed to go around it so I'm curious as to how that could be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are most likely doing it like Chatfuel (and other platforms): There is ONE bot that is reviewed and ready to go, with all the neccessary webhooks. If you create a new bot on those platforms, you don´t really create a new bot on the Facebook platform. It more or less just connects their bot to your Page.

Comment: Be aware though that this way you will have all customers “sitting in the same boat.” Let one of them misbehave enough to get your app blocked or removed by Facebook, and it is gone for _everyone_.

Comment: yeah, you depend on 2 different platforms that way (facebook and the bot provider).

Comment: @luschn i know this is an old question, but still. How would the system know which bot is receiving the message? I mean, when the webhook is invvoked, how does the back-end know what bot to use if the URL is common for all the bots? I also can't believe it lets all bots depend on policy enforcement on one application. With chatfuel, powering potentially thousands of bots, seems like a pretty fragile and non-extensible way to go...